# Как оставить только 4 строчки в файле, а остальные удалить? Python

Tags: python, строки, файлы

В файл записываются строчки из пользовательского input. Когда число записанных строчек станет больше 4, надо удалить те, что ниже и вывести пользователю только 4 строчки (мы не знаем, какие строки написаны в файле). Нельзя использовать новый файл и другие библиотеки, кроме стандартной.
Например:

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
---
line1
line2
line3
line4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with open("filename") as f:
    head = [next(f) for _ in range(4)]
print(head)
```